# Customized barlegend changes appearance when placed next to a plot

Tags: legending

I created a simple barlegend:

```
barlegend = BarLegend[{Hue[#] &, {0, .7}}]
```

[image]

However, when I tried placing this legend next to any plot, the legend appears differently.  It seems that when placed in a plot, my custom range [0, 0.7] is scaled to [0,1] as input for the Hue function.  How could I make the legend appear in the same way as it is created?   Thank you.

```
barlegend = BarLegend[{Hue[#] &, {0, .7}}] 

Plot[t + 10, {t, 0, 2}, PlotLegends -> barlegend, 
 Epilog -> Text["Any plot", {.5, 11}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `barlegend` with `Legended`

```
Legended[Plot[t + 10, {t, 0, 2}, Epilog -> Text["Any plot", {.5, 11}]], barlegend]
```

[image]

or add the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` to `Plot`:

```
Plot[t + 10, {t, 0, 2}, PlotLegends -> barlegend, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Epilog -> Text["Any plot", {.5, 11}]]
```

> same picture